# I installed awscli. I want to configure aws account using email Id and password through aws-cli. Is it possible? Please suggest me

Tags: aws-cli

Assume, the user is new to AWS.  They do not know how to create IAM access key and secret key.  The user knows only their email address and password.

Is there a way to configure aws-cli to use email address and password?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aws-cli with e-mail id and password.

If you have your email id and the password then login to AWS console with that, create a new user in IAM, create the access key and secret access key and then use that in aws-cli